# Definition of Euler phi function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why is $\phi(n)$ defined to be $$\phi(n) = |\{ 0 \le b < n \mid gcd(b,n) = 1 \}|$$ rather than $$\phi(n) = |\{ 0 < b < n \mid gcd(b,n) = 1 \}|$$
?

I realize it doesn't make a practical difference (right?), but since $0$ is never in the set it seems odd to go out of our way to include it.

Comment: Which source gave this definition? I think it's standard to take $0<b$.

Comment: Interesting. Koblitz' _Number Theory_ defines it with $0 \le b$, but I guess that's nonstandard (which more or less answers the question).

Comment: David M. Burton's $Elementary$ $Number$ $Theory$ defines it as $1\leq b$.

Comment: The totient function counts the invertible elements of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, so it is consistent to include representatives for each remainder class in the definition. Of course, it is also trivial that the class of $0$ is never invertible.

Answer (score 0):

I have usually seen it defined using $1 \leqslant b \leqslant n$.

We need to include one (and only one) of $0$ and $n$ to get the right result for $n = 1$. If we only looked at $0 < b < n$, we would obtain $\phi(1) = 0$, which is not a convenient definition (with $\phi(1) = 1$, we have a multiplicative function).

If one thinks of the interpretation of $\phi(n)$ as the number of units in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, as in [LutzL's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765253/definition-of-euler-phi-function#comment1590987_765253) it is natural to include $0$ rather than $n$ since typically one considers the representatives $0$ through $n-1$ for the elements of that ring and not $1$ through $n$.